# Milnor's exercise: for any manifold $M$, $\mathrm{Hom}(C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})\cong M$

Tags: differential-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, manifolds

I am studying some chapters of Kolar-Michor-Slovak, *Natural Operations in Differential Geometry*, in particular the one on Weil bundles, where they present the famous "Milnor's exercise". They give two similar proofs, one much shorter than the other, supposedly because of omitted details. I would like to understand it better.

So we have to prove the:

> **Theorem** For any manifold $M$, $\mathrm{Hom}(C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})\cong M$

Where $\mathrm{Hom}$ refers to morphisms of commutative unital algebras and $\cong$ to bijection of sets (I suppose).

Now the short proof goes like this:

Consider an homomorphism of algebras $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}\xrightarrow{\phi}\mathbb{R})$, *by the usual short exact sequence argument*, $\ker(\phi)\leq C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ is an ideal of codimension $1$ (*notice that such an homomorphism cannot be the zero map, since $\phi(1_\mathbb{R})=1\in\mathbb{R}$*).
Now, consider the following system of subsets of $M$, where $V(f)=f^{-1}(0)$:
$$\{V(f)\mid (M\xrightarrow{f}\mathbb{R})\in \ker(\phi)\}$$
this is clearly a filter of closed sets of $M$, since $V(f^2+g^2)=V(f)\cap V(g)$.
Find a function $M\xrightarrow{f^*}\mathbb{R}\in \ker(\phi)$ which is unbounded on each non-compact closed subset of $M$ (*for instance a positive proper function, such as the square of the geodesic distance w.r.t. any Riemannian metric*).  **Then $V(f^*)$ is a compact set contained in  $\bigcap_{f\in \ker(\phi)} V(f)$, which is then nonempty.**
Let $x_0$ be one of its elements.
Then for any $f\in C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ $f-\phi(f)1$ is in $\ker(\phi)$ so $(f-\phi(f)1)(x_0)=0$, and $\phi(f)=f(x_0)$.
So $x_0$ completely determines $\phi$ and the map $\phi\mapsto x_0$ is the desired bijection.

I have fetched the italicised details. What I am having trouble understanding is the bold passage. Moreover I don't see where we use the fact that the given system of sets is a filter and that $\ker(\phi)$ has codimension 1: I suspect these are relevant for the bold passage also.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $V(f^\ast)$ is compact because $f^\ast$ is proper. $V(f^\ast)$ is nonempty because otherwise $f^\ast$ is invertible (and cannot be in the non-trivial kernel).

Comment: The codimension of the kernel is used to know that we just need to know that every element of the kernel is zero at a point $x_0$ and to know $\phi (1) $ to have the conclusion. But I don't know why $f^*$ exists and why its $V (f^*) $ is contained in the intersection of the $V (f) $ for $f $ in the kernel.

Comment: If you know that such a $f^*$ exists, then, if the intersection of the $V (f) $ is empty, then the intersections of the $V (f^2+f^{*2}) $ will be empty, so, by compactness, the intersection of a finite number of them will be empty, so you have , by taking the sum of these functions, you would have a function never vanishing in the kernel. A contradiction.

Comment: I think you have a typo, the argument gives that $V(f^*)$ should contain the intersection, not be contained in it. Additionally your construction of $f^*$ may not lie in $\ker(\phi)$. The hard part is showing that $\bigcap_{f\in \ker(\phi)}V(f)$ is not empty, once you have that it is elementary to see that it is a single point.

Comment: Sorry about commenting again : with $g^*$ such that $g^*$ is proper can give you such a $f^*$ with $f^*:=g^*- \phi (g^*) 1$.

Comment: Here's another way to phrase the argument: if there's not a point $x\in M$ such that every element of $ker(\phi)$ vanishes at $x$, then $M$ is covered by the open sets $M\setminus V(f)$ as $f$ ranges over $ker(\phi)$. But then $V(f^\ast)$, being compact, is covered by finitely many of these open sets, say corresponding to $f_1,\ldots,f_n$. That means $(f^\ast)^2+\sum f_i^2$ is an element of the kernel which is non-zero everywhere, contradicting that the kernel is non-trivial.

Comment: The proposed function $f꙳$ (square of geodesic distance) is not in $\text{Ker}(\phi)$ and I do not see any argument in
the original post or in the comments leading to a function $f꙳$ in $\text{Ker}(\phi)$ with the desired properties.  In
fact the proposed function $f꙳$ is not even proper: if $M$ is the unit disk with Riemannian metric induced from the
plane then ${f꙳}^{-1}([-2, 2])=M$, which is not compact!  I thus seems to me that we're pretty far from a solution!

Comment: @Ruy I am quite sceptical myself. Still what you see above is taken from a fairly important book so I wonder what the authors had in mind. Anyay they provide another proof where the result comes as a corollary of a general  and difficult result, one can always go with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we observe that what we really need in the proof is that $\bigcap_{f \in \operatorname{ker}(\phi)} V(f)\ne  \emptyset$. The proof follows from that just as you written it. Now
$$V(f^*) \supset \bigcap_{f \in \operatorname{ker}(\phi)} V(f)=\bigcap_{f \in \operatorname{ker}(\phi)} V(f)\cap V(f^*),$$
so we can use the following characterization of compactness: Any collection of closed subsets of $V(f^*)$ with the finite intersection property has nonempty intersection.

Now we prove that each finite subset $\{V(f_i)\}_{i=1}^n\subset \ker \phi$ has non empty intersection. Otherwise $g:=\sum_i f_i^2>0$ and $g\in \ker \phi$. This can't be true because if $g$ is an invertible element then $1_\mathbb{R} \in \ker \phi$( Contradiction to $\ker \phi$ has codimension $1$).

We can conclude that $\bigcap_{f \in \operatorname{ker}(\phi)} V(f)=\bigcap_{f \in \operatorname{ker}(\phi)} V(f)\cap V(f^*)$ has a non empty intersection by the compactness of $V(f^*)$.

Some observations:

The hard part is to construct $f^*$ as this shows that ${f^*}^{-1}(0)$ is compact.

Another equivalent definition of compactness of a space $X$ is: Every filter on $X$ has a cluster point. You could probably use that for the proof. We have seen in the proof that I  imitate the same reasoning used ot show $\{V(f) \mid(M \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{R}) \in \operatorname{ker}(\phi)\}$ is a filter. I was not confident enough with the definitions of filters to go in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

This is a proof of the "hard part" mentioned in  @Elad's answer.

**Lemma**.  A smooth manifold $M$ admits a smooth real valued function $f$ such that
$$
  \lim_{x\to \infty }f(x) = \infty ,
  $$
(in the sense that for every $a>0$, there exists a compact subset $K\subseteq M$, such that $f(x)>a$, for every $x\in M\setminus
K$)
if and only if $M$ is $\sigma $-compact.

*Proof*. For the  "only if" part notice that,  given $f$ as above, one has that $f^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ is compact for every real
number $a$, and
$$
  M= \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N}f^{-1}((-\infty,n]).
  $$

Conversely, let $\{K_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a family of compact subsets of $M$  such that   $M= \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N}K_n$.  By a
well known trick, based on the local compactness of $M$, we may assume WLOG that each $K_n$ is contained in the interior
of $K_{n+1}$.

By Lemma (1.3.2) in [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~petersen/manifolds.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Epetersen/manifolds.pdf) (Smooth Urysohn Lemma), for each $n$ in $\mathbb
N$ we may choose a nonegative smooth function $f_n$ vanishing on $K_n$ and taking on the value 1 on $M\setminus \text{int}(K_{n+1})$ (and
hence also on $M\setminus K_{n+1}$).

Defining
$$
  f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  f_n(x), \quad \forall x\in  M,
  $$
we claim that, for every $x$ in $M$,  there exists   a neighborhood $V$ of $x$,  and a natural number $m$, such that
$f_n=0$ on $V$, for every $n\geq m$.

To see this, find some $i$ such that $x\in  K_i$.   It then suffices to take
$V=\text{int}(K_{i+1})$ and $m=i+1$.

This said, it is clear that the  above function $f$ is well defined and smooth.

To see that  $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x) = \infty $, observe that if $x\not\in  K_{m+1}$, then  surely $x\not\in K_{n+1}$, for  every $n\leq m$,  whence
$$
  f(x) \geq   \sum_{n=1}^m f_n(x) = m.
  $$
This completes the proof of the Lemma.  QED

---

Back to the question, let us assume that  $M$ is $\sigma $-compact, so we may pick  $f$  as in the
Lemma.

Setting
$$
  f^*=f-\phi(f)1,
  $$
one has  that $f^*\in \text{Ker}(\phi)$, and clearly also   $\lim_{x\to \infty }f^*(x) = \infty $, so we have that
$$
  V(f^*) =   {f^*}^{-1}(0)
  $$
is compact, as desired.