# Duality between differentiable manifolds and algebras of $C^\infty$ functions.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, category-theory, manifolds

As a corollary of [Milnor's excercise: for any manifold $M$, $Hom(C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})\cong M$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3934108/milnors-excercise-for-any-manifold-m-homc-inftym-mathbbr-mathbbr), we obtain that

> **Theorem** Given any two manifolds $M_1,M_2$ the mapping:
> $$C^\infty(M_1,M_2)\rightarrow Hom(C^\infty(M_2,\mathbb{R}),C^\infty(M_1,\mathbb{R}))\quad f\mapsto g\xrightarrow{f^*}g\circ f$$
> is a canonical bijection

Now, this expresses the fact that the functor $C^\infty(\cdot,\mathbb{R}): \mathsf{Man}\rightarrow\mathsf{CAlg}$ is fully faithful.

If we restrict to the subcategory of $\mathsf{CAlg}$ whose skeleton is given by the image of the functor, we obtain a duality.

My first question is: has this subcategory a particular name? Can we say something more about it?
Secondly, the result above reminds one of the immediate consequences of the Yoneda Lemma, but obviously it is not a proper instance of it. Can we link the two somehow?
Thirdly: how does this result binds to the algebraic analogue for algebraic varieties and to the Gelfand duality for topological spaces? Can we homogeneously treat *any* category space as the dual of some subcategory of $\mathsf{CAlg}$?

Comment: You may be interested in reading Nestruev's *Smooth Manifolds and Observables* which I believe attempts to use this as a foundation for differential geometry: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387955438

Comment: Thanks a lot: I will take a look at it, your recommendations are always fantastic!

Comment: I am a bit confused about your notation - is $C^{\infty}(M_1,M_2)$ meant to be smooth maps from $M_1$ to $M_2$? If so, in your definition of $f^*$ the domain element $f \mapsto g$ seems to be an element of $Hom(C^{\infty}(M_2),C^{\infty}(M_1))$ unless I an mistaken.

Comment: @Math, the notation is a bit poor here, this must have confused you. I defined an assignment which sends $f\in C^\infty(M_1,M_2)\mapsto f^*\in Hom(C^\infty(M_2,\mathbb{R}),C^\infty(M_1,\mathbb{R}))$. $f^*$ takes a $g\in C^\infty(M_2,\mathbb{R})$ and outputs the composition $g\circ f\in C^\infty(M_1,\mathbb{R})$